# Magento 2: No options under configuration>general>design

Tags: magento2, theme, magento-2.0.4

Since I updated to 2.0.4 I noticed there is no option in the backend to select a theme. (not sure if this is the cause or it happend before) Under **Configuration > General > Design** there is only the option to edit **Search Engine Robots**. Under that section there is no 'Theme' section that did used to be there??
Screenshot: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2xXr.jpg)

However in the database theme option is present:

`14 | default | 0 | design/theme/theme_id | 4`

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Anything in the log ?

Comment: Did you make compile everything?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism It seems the log is only for layout.xml, here is a copy of `system.log`: http://textuploader.com/5wjlo

Comment: I did a fresh install of magento 2.0.4 via github but still have similar errors. `system/debug.log`: http://textuploader.com/5wj2r. Quick workaround is to manually insert `design/theme/theme_id` to `core_config_data`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like it has been moved to **`Content > Configuration`**. There a table will be displayed with the `Website`, `Store`, and `Store View`. If you select "Edit" under the Action column you'll be able to set the default theme there.

Comment: yah in 2.1 its been moved to Content > Configuration

Comment: Thanks very much. did not know this.